# What does it mean "whenever sqlerror exit 9"?

Tags: sql, unix

What does *whenever sqlerror exit 9* mean?

And does the number 9 represent anything? I was thinking maybe it's a sqlerror code but I couldn't find a sqlerror code with a number 9.

Comment: It means whenever an sqlerror occurs then exit with return code 9.

Comment: @juergen d I see people uses exit 1 exit 0 as well. What does the number represent?

Comment: Does not have to be a specific meaning in general. Maybe a user script uses that info for further processing. Maybe it is not used at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically exiting 0 means success and non-zero means an error.  The number of the exit code refers to where the error occurred, and is programmer-defined.  Perhaps your program would exit 1 if login failed, 2 if a query returned no rows where at least one was expected, etc.  A wrapper program can call this one, then use the return code to see if it ran successfully or not.  If not, you know where in the code it failed by the number.  Used as you are dealing with, they are called magic numbers.  Who knows what they mean as apparently the original developer never at least defined them in a comment.  Now you know why magic numbers should be avoided.  Instead, define return codes as constants with a meaningful name at the top of your program, then refer to them by that name when used.  Whoever maintains the code after you will sing your praises instead of cursing your existence!  In Oracle PL/SQL for instance, I'd do something like this:

```
...
-- Define return codes.  
ERR_NOLOGIN       CONSTANT INTEGER := 1;
ERR_NOROWS        CONSTANT INTEGER := 2;
ERR_TOO_MANY_ROWS CONSTANT INTEGER := 3;
...
-- Then in your error handing:
WHENEVER ERROR EXIT ERR_NOLOGIN;  -- No magic number makes for 
                                  -- easier to read code.
...
```